# Changing LaTeX font in pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have just started to use LaTeX (TeXworks, pdfLaTeX) and I am using Windows 7. How can I change the font to Garamond with math support? I found this from the LaTeX font catalogue but it does not work:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section*{Garamond}
\subsection*{\textbackslash normalfont}
\normalfont\normalfont
\input catalogue
\subsection*{\textbackslash itshape}
\normalfont\itshape
\input catalogue
\newpage
\normalfont\normalfont
\input fonttable
\section{Math}
\normalfont
\[
\mathbf{B}(P)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf{I}\times\hat{r}'}{r'^2}dl = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\,I\!\int\frac{d\boldsymbol{l}\times\hat{r}'}{r'^2}
\]
```

It gives following errors:

```
garamond(1).tex
18
I can't find file `catalogue'.
l.18 \input catalogue

garamond(1).tex
15
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/mb/n' undefined using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 15.
```

When I delete the lines containing `\input`, it gives the following error:

```
garamond(1).tex
15
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/mb/n' undefined using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 15.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `OT1/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/mdugm/b/it' undefined using `OML/mdugm/m/it' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `OMS/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMX/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `OMX/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `OML/mdugm/b/it' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `MDA/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `MDA/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex
26
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `MDB/mdugm/b/n' undefined using `MDB/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 26.

garamond(1).tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: the right way to use the `\input` command is `\input{nameofthefile}`.

Answer (score 1):

To set both text and math fonts to Garamond for the whole document, use:

```
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

All the other stuff in your code is really unrelated. (I suppose you copy-pasted the code.)

The `\input` command tries to input a plaintext/.tex file but there is no file named `catalogue` in your working directory. The reason while your code doesn't compile is the missing files it tries to `\input`, and a missing `\end{document}`. Everything else is fine.
The font fine-tuning commands there are unnecessary I think.

Comment: Now wrote it like this: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Garamond}
Text

\end{document}  But it gives error in Console output: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Install the `garamond` type1 font in your TEXMF directory and run the `mktexlsr`.